# GNU screen session dies when I open vim or vi

Tags: vim, gnu-screen

Sometimes it dies in the moment a file is opened. Sometimes it allows me to browse the same file and dies on tenth PageDown, for example. I set "term xterm" in .screenrc.

Comment: Not a solution, but I just wanted to say that I had similar problems with vim and screen until I ditched screen in favor of [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Can you provide a few more details about your setup, it might help.  Like the OS, and any other relevant details.

For the record, I've used screen and vim for years on many different OSes without a problem.

Comment: When you say "PageDown" -- are you referring to the physical page down key? or Ctrl-F? If the physical, key, do you have something in your .vimrc which binds that to something special?